# Android: Listview not displaying properly with simpleCursorAdapter

Tags: android, sqlite, cursor, android-listview, simplecursoradapter

Ive been struggling for a while with my rather simple app. 
This is my onCreate in my listactivity class:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    DB db = new DB(this);
    db.open();
    cur = db.getData(); //cursor with all data from an SQLite db

    String[] from = new String[] { DB.KEY_FIRSTNAME,
            DB.KEY_LASTNAME, DB.KEY_BDATE};
    int[] to = new int[] { NOT SURE WHAT TO PUT HERE };
    startManagingCursor(cur);
    setListAdapter(new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, 
    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, cur, from, to));

    db.close();

    }
```

The getData() method returns a cursor from an sqlite database. the int[] used by the adapter defined over is where I think the problem lies, but I have no idea how to solve it. The list I get out is either blank. Only lines resembling the number of entries in the database or only 1 of the columns. I have tried int[] {android.R.id.text1, android.R.id.text1, android.R.id.text1, android.R.id.text1} and fewer entries, and text2 and Ive now tried to just make a textview and call that, but then it goes completely blank again.

I hope you can help me wrap my head around this. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `to` variable stores the R.id's of where you want to map your data to. For example, if the layout (android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1) has three TextViews in it, named fName, lName and bDate you would place those in the `int array` and it will map the data in the from fields to the on screen layout components in the to fields.

```
int[] to = new int[] {R.id.fName, R.id.lName, R.id.bDate};
```

Comment: So I make need to make 3 TextViews and put those into the listview? Or should I change my layout and create a ListView layout with three TextView fileds in it? I thought I could put them directly into the listview by doing it this way. Apparently I misunderstood something. Thanks so far

Comment: Check out this quick example of using the Simple Adapter. It really breaks it down. http://eureka.ykyuen.info/2010/01/03/android-simple-listview-using-simpleadapter/

Comment: Somehow Im still not able to get it to work. I changed int[] to = new int[] { R.id.c1, R.id.c2, R.id.c3 };
And created an xml file containing a linearlayout horizontal with 3 textviews. the c1, c2 and c3 are the TextViews ids. I also made another xml file with only a ListView: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/layout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

</ListView>
It still only shows the lines with no text in it :S

Comment: Did you make sure to load those new layout files within your code?

Comment: The c references in my int[] loads them as the 'destination' in the adapter, doesnt it? And i put the new layout into the simpleCursorAdapter where i previously had simple_list_item1

Comment: I finally managed to do it! I needed to reference the textviews in the layout, whereas I was referrencing textviews in a seperate xml.